# Dataset of graph coloring with the chromatic number of the instances

Tags: graph, dataset, graph-coloring

Do you know any graph coloring datasets?
I want a dataset of graphs where the chromatic number of each instance is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DIMACS once ran a graph colouring challenge and produced a database

https://mat.tepper.cmu.edu/COLOR/instances.html